# switching between JInternalFrames

Tags: java, jinternalframe

I did asked the same question here before but the difference is that, on my previous question, I was only using JFrame, but after heeding Mad Programmer's advice, I switched to JInternalFrame but I'm kind of experiencing the same problem, or a lesser problem so to speak.

My program is re-sizing my JFrame based on the JInternalFrame's given size. But after switching back and forth to each internal frame, one of them gets kind of messy. Please see the images below to see what I mean.

[image: first run]

[image: from login frame]

Here's my code that shows login JInternalFrame (which in the 'gui' class)

```
loginframe.add(signIn,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dpane.add(loginframe);

    try {
        loginframe.setMaximum(true);
        mainFrame.setSize(355, 220);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //This frame handles the main system's interface.
    mframe.getContentPane().add(opt1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mframe.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mframe.getContentPane().add(list, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mframe.setVisible(false);
    dpane.add(mframe);
```

Here's my code that shows my main JInternalFrame (which in a different class)

```
try {
                            gui.mframe.setMaximum(true);
                            gui.mframe.setSize(800, 500);
                            Dimension get = gui.mframe.getSize();
                            gui.mainFrame.setSize(get.width, get.height);
                            gui.mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        gui.mframe.setVisible(true);
                        gui.mframe.toFront();
                        gui.loginframe.setVisible(false);
```

And here's the code that calls the login JInternalFrame from the main JInternalFrame

```
    try {
                loginframe.setMaximum(true);
                mainFrame.setSize(355, 220);
                mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {    
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            loginframe.setVisible(true);
            //loginframe.toFront();
            mframe.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: `gui.mframe.setMaximum(true);` followed by `gui.mframe.setSize(800, 500);` seems counter intuitive. Do you want the window to be maximised or sized to your dimensions?

Comment: I want the window to be sized to my dimension. I tried to remove the setSize then I my main JInternalFrame was disorganized from the very first run.

Comment: My first thought would be to use `pack`

Comment: not working either, here's my code                                                                              try {
        //gui.mframe.setMaximum(true);
//gui.mframe.setSize(new Dimension(800,500));        //Dimension get = gui.mframe.getSize();        gui.mframe.pack();        gui.mainFrame.setSize(800, 500);     gui.mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }